# What is the name of the shell-script which uses the word "ROF" to end a for-loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

More than five years ago someone taught me how to write shell scripts for Linux.

My code looked like this:

```
FOR ...
   do things
ROF
```

I was told that it was BASH script (Bourne Again Shell). However, anytime that I look for example of BASH script on the internet, they do not use the word `ROF` to end a for-loop and they do not use `FI` to end an if-statement.

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    # must have at least one command in loop
    echo $i  # just print value of i
done
```

What is the **name** of the shell script which uses the key-words `ROF` and `FI`?

I am trying to identify the name of the language.

Comment: `What is the name of the shell-script which uses the word "ROF" to end a for-loop?` There is no such thing in `bash` or a POSIX shell compliant. A `for` loop ends with a `done`, see `help for` and `fi` is for an `if` clause/statement, see `help if`

Comment: Stephen Bourne's original [V7 shell source code](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/mac.h) used some macros to replace backwards keywords with real C (I think he really liked Algol 68), but even it didn't use a ROF, and the shell language itself didn't either.

Comment: @shawn: .... which is a pity. The language would have become even more bizarre. After all, a `select` would have been terminated by `tceles` and the `while` by `elihw`. The history of programming really missed a great opportunity here.

Comment: Neither `FOR` (all uppercase) nor `ROF` are keywords in bash, but you can of course define your own commands with those names, which then can do anything you like.

Comment: @user1934428 I remember reading a Knuth paper where he mentioned seeing students mockingly have things like `comment blah tnemmoc`

Comment: @shawn : And don't forget [this](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dharel/SCANNED.PAPERS/DoConsideredOd.pdf) seminal paper on that matter  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a scripting language called [nodots](https://github.com/healeycodes/nodots-lang), which among other things has a `for...rof` construct.

In bash however, there is no `rof` keyword. It does have other reversed word patterns (`if...fi` and `case...esac`), but not the one you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The language you are referring to is likely NOT Bash. Bash does not use "ROF" to end a for-loop or "FI" to end an if-statement. It uses "done" to end a for-loop and "fi" to end an if-statement, as shown in the example you provided.
It is possible that the "ROF" and "FI" keywords were used in some other shell scripting language, but it is not a standard convention in Bash or any widely-used shell scripting language.
I would recommend reviewing the syntax and conventions of Bash scripting to better understand the language you were taught. There are many resources available online, including tutorials and documentation from the official Bash website.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).